# Broken Java Mac 10.6

Tags: java, macos, osx-snow-leopard, macports

Some background:

On Mac OS X 10.6 using Macports and I have `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` set in my .bash_profile.

The problem:

When I run `java -version` I get this error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Unable to load native library: libjava.jnilib

By way of one helpful [forum thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2089136), I've discovered the problem is some files in my '/opt/local/lib' directory are causing trouble because of the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` I've set.

When I remove the files starting with libgif, libjpeg, libpng and libtiff from '/opt/local/lib', the problem goes away and `java -version' works, but the ports that depend on those files break.

Anyone know of a way I can keep the files and still get java to work properly?  Possibly setting the java path, which I'm not quite sure how to do and all my attempts have failed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Don't set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Because of this env var, the dynamic linker dyld, is finding `/opt/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib` etc. instead of the different `/System/Library/Frameworks//ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Resources/libJPEG.dylib` that it needs.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to work on OS X Lion:

unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

Seems one possible cause of this a file protection problem?  See my post over in this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850624/mac-os-x-lion-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-unable-to-load-native/8069147#8069147).

Comment: Please don't post answers that are just links to other posts. At Stack Overflow, answers should actually contain self-contained solutions to their questions. Links are great, but they should only be used to provide additional information.