# shell_exec() in PHP on Mac OSX using MAMP gives Error occurred during initialization of VM Unable to load native library: libjava.jnilib

Tags: java, php, mamp

I've looked all over for an answer and it appears I need to set my $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to something that knows where my missing library is but I can't tell what that might be.

My machine is Mac OS X and I have PHP5 running under MAMP. I have a shell command for an executable I've created that runs fine in terminal but doesn't work at all from my PHP app. I get the following error:

`$ Error occurred during initialization of VM Unable to load native library: libjava.jnilib`

I think I just need to find that library and add the dir to the variable listed above but I can't seem to find it. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You should try to configure the $PATH environment variable (and / or others ) using [`putenv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php)

Comment: could you point me at how to find what path I need to add?

Comment: path to libjava.jnilib

Answer (score 0):

As [Broken Java Mac 10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482450/broken-java-mac-10-6) mentions the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH must be unset. Not sure why, it seems to be needed on Unix systems but not MacOSX.

If MAMP sets to /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib here's how to disable it: Edit /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars and comment out the following lines

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
So that it looks like this:

## DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

## export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

This should fix the problem and java 1.6 can run fine.

For more information, check here: [Java 1.6 Broken when called by background Symfony task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650013/java-1-6-broken-when-called-by-background-symfony-task)

Answer (score 0):

This also worked for me on another environment:

```
<?php
  exec('export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=""; java -version');
?>
```

References:
- https://drupal.org/node/1257654
- [Calling java from PHP exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278868/calling-java-from-php-exec)